# Corepresentable functor definition.

Tags: category-theory, definition, representable-functor

I have been searching for the definition of a Corepresentable functor here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+object but still I did not get what exactly is its definition. I also love the definition of representable functor from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor but still I do not exactly understand the definition of a Corepresentable functor. Could someone tell me the defintion please and how it differs from the definition of representable functor?

Comment: It is written in the link you provide:  $F(Y) = \mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A corepresentable is just $\mathrm{Hom}(c,-)$ as opposed to the representable $\mathrm{Hom}(-,c).$ Many people will call both representable.

Comment: Just to add another characterization: a corepresentable functor is also just a representable functor in the opposite category, since for any category $\mathscr{C}$ and any object $c$ therein, we have $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(-,c)=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}(c,-)$.

Comment: is $c$ your object?

Comment: I see that your notation for corepresentable is opposite to the one in the link of wikipedia

Comment: @Emptymind It's not that Wikipedia would call $\mathrm{Hom}(-,c)$ corepresentable, but that their convention would call both functors representable. And yes, $c$ is an object.